# Какое событие отвечает за клик по пустой области в ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Я пытаюсь реализовать открытие pop-up меню типа такого:

[image: pop-up]

Проблема в том что я обрабатываю событие так:

```
MasterListView.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(masterListView_mouseClick);
```

А потом.

```
private void masterListView_mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip rightClickContextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();

            rightClickContextMenu.Items.Add("Добавить").Name = "Add";
            rightClickContextMenu.Items.Add("Удалить").Name = "Delete";
            rightClickContextMenu.Items.Add("Подробнее").Name = "Details";
            rightClickContextMenu.Show(MasterListView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            rightClickContextMenu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(masterStripHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            // левая кнопка мыши
        }
    }
```

Однако я так-же хочу отдельно обработать клик по "фону" элемента, что полезно в случае, когда запрос ничего не вернул. (Выделил зону на рисунке)

[image: Нужно чтобы можно было кликнуть на пустую область и вызвать событие]

Но не могу найти такого события, а городить огород не хотелось бы.
Подскажите пожалуйста как такое лучше реализовать.

Comment: А нельзя просто обрабатывать клик на элемент ListView?

Comment: @bearpro нет. Ведь запрос может не вернуть ничего и как следствие не создастся ни одного элемента ListView.

На ум приходит только костыль: создавать пустую строку, если запрос ничего не вернул. Но это не годится.

Comment: Можно не `Click`, а событие `ContextMenuOpening` использовать, и внутри обработчика решать, открываться или нет. Создавать новое контекстное меню на каждый клик - плохая практика.

Comment: @aepot создание обработчика происходит единожды, в методе onLoad. Иначе он бы ими спамил по нескольку раз при повторных открытиях. В этом плане всё ок.

Comment: Но в обработчике вы на каждый клик создаете новое контексное меню `new ContextMenuStrip()`

Comment: @aepot да... Точно. Затупил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView1.MouseUp += (s,e) => 
{
  if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) // <-- необходима данная проверка
    form1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // <-- тут вместо form1.Text вызывать вывод меню
}
```

Comment: Забавно что работает. Спасибо.
Мне, правда, не понятно почему аналогично нельзя обработать событие MouseClick.

Comment: MouseClick тоже по идее должен работать, но я им не пользуюсь, как и ListView, тут подсказать не могу.
Вероятно разработчики сделали для дочерних контролов его специально эксклюзивно.